# Angular 4 set values to form input field of iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

I am using iframe with other domain in angular 4 application And want to assign values inside iframe form input fields.

is there any way we can achieve this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem before: I think in this case, you will need to do two things:

- ulitize a messaging layer between the two applications (the embedding app, and the iframe app)
- extend the code of **both** applications (so the iframe can handle the messages you send to it trough the browser)

If the application is on a different domain, they cannot interact directly because of the [Same-origin policy.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

To achive this, you must ulitize [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Basic idea:

1. embedding application starts, iframe application starts
2. iframe application subscribes for messages with `window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);`
3. embedding aplication sends the message trought the iframe with something like `@ViewChild('iframeRef') iframeRef: ElementRef;` 
   `this.iframeRef.nativeElement.contentWindow.postMessage({some message object to the iframe}, '*', []);`

   4. iframe app handles the message

Note: due to security concerns, you might wanna check the origin of the message event, and only handle messages that is sent by the source you trust.

```
 function receiveMessage(event){
    console.log("Received a message From: Angular", event);

    // if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    // return;
    // todo: this is crucial for being secure!

    ....
  }
```